# Rust: use of partially moved values

Tags: rust

In Rust 0.8:

```
struct TwoStr {
  one: ~str,
  two: ~str,
}

#[test]
fn test_contents() {
  let strs = TwoStr {
    one: ~"pillar",
    two: ~"post",
  };

  assert_eq!(strs.one, ~"pillar");
  assert_eq!(strs.two, ~"post");
}
```

The code won't even compile. The `rust test` thinks there's an error in the second `assert_eq`:

> error: use of partially moved value: `strs`

It is somewhat counter-intuitive. I mean, whatever effects the first `assert_eq` may have, it should be well out of the scope when the execution reaches the second `assert_eq`. Unless of course, it does some spawn behind the scene. Does it?

If not, why this mysterious error? Hopefully there's no fundamental flaws in my understanding of Rust pointers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Rust 0.8, `assert_eq!` is defined as

```
macro_rules! assert_eq (
    ($given:expr , $expected:expr) => (
        {
            let given_val = $given;
            let expected_val = $expected;
            // check both directions of equality....
            if !((given_val == expected_val) && (expected_val == given_val)) {
                fail!(\"assertion failed: `(left == right) && (right == \
                left)` (left: `%?`, right: `%?`)\", given_val, expected_val);
            }
        }
    )
)
```

Note here that it moves both arguments into local let-bindings `given_val` and `expected_val`. This is what is causing your error.

In current master, this has been fixed. `assert_eq!` now takes references to the arguments:

```
macro_rules! assert_eq (
    ($given:expr , $expected:expr) => (
        {
            let given_val = &($given);
            let expected_val = &($expected);
            // check both directions of equality....
            if !((*given_val == *expected_val) &&
                 (*expected_val == *given_val)) {
                fail!("assertion failed: `(left == right) && (right == left)` \
                       (left: `{:?}`, right: `{:?}`)", *given_val, *expected_val)
            }
        }
    )
)
```

This means that it no longer moves its arguments, which fixes your error.

If you need to stick with rust 0.8, you can change this to using `assert!()` instead and do the comparison directly, which will avoid the move. But my recommendation is to upgrade to latest master.

Answer (score 3):

It works on Git master. It must be a bug that was fixed after 0.8 was cut. In general, the released versions are not constrained to be particularly stable before release - they're essentially just snapshots.

The definition of the `assert_eq!` macro, in [libsyntax](https://github.com/mozilla/rust/blob/a6310f6ad3434a03d5c257db5eae85b7b7522c29/src/libsyntax/ext/expand.rs#L768), takes references to the arguments, so the arguments should not be moved and you can use them after you call the macro.

If you do find another bug, try to compile master if you can, or just make a new [issue](https://github.com/mozilla/rust/issues?direction=desc&sort=created&state=open).